# Creating a repeating integer array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I just want to make an array with the dates of a month. So the dates will start from 1 until 31 at most.

The obvious way, I know is a manual way:

```
$date_array = array( '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', ..., '31' );
```

But I'm looking for an automated way, like a simple `for loop`, making me my desired automatically generated dates:

```
for($Idx=1;$Idx<32;$Idx++) {
  var_dump($Idx);
}
```

Just need to put them in an array.

#### IMAGINATION

```
$my_date_array = makeArray( $Idx );
```

*makeArray() - hah!* :)

**Possible?**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
function makeArray ($calendar, $month, $year) { 
   return range (1, cal_days_in_month ($calendar, $month, $year));
}
```

*Example*

```
$aMyArray = makeArray (CAL_GREGORIAN, 8, 2003);
```

*References*

- [range](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.range.php) `array range ( mixed $start , mixed $end [, number $step = 1 ] )`
- [cal_days_in_month](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php) `int cal_days_in_month ( int $calendar , int $month , int $year )`

Comment: +1 looks like tested and well prepared example  :)

Comment: +1, works exactly as expected.

Comment: Edited the answer: without returning the function was generating NULL.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = time(); // A Unix timestamp, so for example 'strtotime("2013-01-01")'.
$array_of_days_in_month = range(1, date("t", $date));
```

`date("t")` will return the number of days in a given month.

Answer (score 0):

use [range()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php):

```
$data = range(1,31);
```

Comment: take in mind this the first value will be with key 0
`array(0=>1, 1=>2, ...30=>31);`

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeArray() {
    $months = array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);
    $array = array();
    foreach($months as $month) {
        $array = array_merge($array, range(1, $month));
    }
    return $array;
}
```

This function takes into account that each month has a different number of days. Watch out for leap-years though!

If you need this from this year, use this. It takes care of leap-years for you!

```
function makeArray() {
    $array = array();
    for($month = 0; $month < 12; $month++) {
        $array = array_merge($array, range(1, date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1)));
    }
    return $array;
}
```